# PHP Mail sending to external e-mail addresses but not internal

Tags: php

Started off with e-mails not being sent at all, but then I used the "-f" parameter in the function, which then works to send to external addresses (Gmail and Hotmail tested so far) but it won't work for addresses that are on the domain though. Just wondering if it's in the code or is it a problem with the server setup?

```
if ($Valid == 1) {
    $_POST = array_map('strip_tags', $_POST);
    $_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);

    $To = "user@domain.ca";

    $Subject = "Online Driver Application";
    $Body = "All the values of the form that was filled out (removed because there was a lot and it doesn't affect the problem)";

    $Headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $Headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $Headers .= 'From: Company <info@domain.ca>' . "\r\n";
    $Headers .= 'Reply-To: no-reply@domain.ca' . "\r\n";
    $Headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($To, $Subject, $Body, $Headers, -finfo@domain.ca);

    echo '<div class="success">Thank You! Your form has been successfully submitted.</div>';
} else {
    if ($ErrorMsg != '') {
        echo '<div class="error">'.$ErrorMsg.'</div>';  
    }
```

Again, unless I have the -finfo@domain.ca in the mail function, e-mails don't get sent out at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a server setup issue, if the server has something like plesk or cpanel installed, but the mx records point elsewhere (different address), the server could be seeing the email as "internal" and skipping connecting out, and delivering the mail to itself..

Comment: They do use Cpanel. Any idea where I need to go to see the mx records?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems OK. This is probably something not setup correctly (like PHP.ini not having the SMTP server or a Firewall blocking something). Also, make sure newlines are `"\n"` in `$Body` I've seen some mail servers rejecting mails because of this. Using mail directly is always tricky. Try to use a library like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) instead. This way you don't have to worry about how to send HTML, attachments...

Comment: I've been wanting to do this, but they've only given me access to cpanel (which I'm new to), can I install said libraries through cpanel?

Comment: @ETx13 Yes I guess you can. I have an host that use cPanel and there is a file manager that let you upload files but it will be a pain if there is many files to do. You should have an FTP access too...

Answer (score 0):

The `additional_parameters` parameter (-f or -r) can be used to pass additional flags as command line options to the program configured to be used when sending mail, as defined by the sendmail_path configuration setting. For example, this can be used to set the envelope sender address when using sendmail with the -f sendmail option.

The additional_parameters(`> 4.2.2`) is disabled in `safe_mode` and the mail() function will expose a warning message and return FALSE when used.

The user that the webserver runs as should be added as a trusted user to the sendmail configuration to prevent a 'X-Warning' header from being added to the message when the envelope sender (-f) is set using this method. For sendmail users, this file is `/etc/mail/trusted-users`.

(or, remove sendmail and install postfix (much easier) if still in problem.)